# Multiple legend entries with multi_line with individual interactivity

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to put multiple legend labels on a legend created by multi line from a ColumnDataSource column. I tried using `legend_label` but this gives me a single label which is the name of the column.

I wasable to get this by using the `legend_group` argument but that prevents me from having individual interactivity in legend entries and all of the labels act as one block - which I guess is expected with the `legend_group` argument.

Here is a simple code example:

```
import numpy as np

import bokeh.plotting as bok
from bokeh.io import curdoc, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Grid, LinearAxis, MultiLine, Plot


N = 9
x = np.linspace(-2, 2, N)
y = x**2

xpts = np.array([-.09, -.12, .0, .12,  .09])
ypts = np.array([-.1,   .02, .1, .02, -.1])

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(
        xs=[xpts*(1+i/10.0)+xx for i, xx in enumerate(x)],
        ys=[ypts*(1+i/10.0)+yy for i, yy in enumerate(y)],
        labels = [[str(i)] for i,_ in enumerate(x)]
    )
)


fig = bok.figure( tools = "pan,box_zoom,wheel_zoom,reset",plot_width=500, plot_height=800)

# This works but not interactive
fig.multi_line(xs="xs", ys="ys", line_color="#8073ac", line_width=2,muted_alpha=0.1,source=source,legend_group='labels')  

# This only shows 'labels' in the legend
#fig.multi_line(xs="xs", ys="ys", line_color="#8073ac", line_width=2,muted_alpha=0.1,source=source,legend_label='labels') 
fig.legend.click_policy = 'mute'


curdoc().add_root(fig)

show(fig)
```

Is there any way to achieve this using multi line or the only option is looping and plotting individual bokeh lines?

Comment: The only option I know is a `loop`. This behaviour was reported on Github [#Issue 10998](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/10998) but this is not a high priority ticket.

Comment: @mosc9575 Thanks for the answer, in to the ```for loop``` I go!